# what is a load balancer predictor

Tags: load-balancing, load-balancer

I understand what a load balancer is but I am not able to understand what a load balancer predictor.

Can anyone please point me to some resource or wiki to undrstand this?

Comment: You may want to consider adding some context. Where did you read this term, how was it used?

Comment: this wiki explains how to configure a load balancer predictor http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/interfaces_modules/services_modules/ace/vA5_1_0/configuration/getting/started/guide/ace_module_gsg/predictr.html

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems, Cisco uses a "predictor" in the Application Control Engine (ACE) to control the load distribution:

> When there is a client request for web services, the ACE selects a
>   server that can successfully fulfill the client request in the
>   shortest amount of time without overloading either the individual
>   server or the server farm.

[Configuring a Load-Balancing Predictor](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/interfaces_modules/services_modules/ace/vA5_1_0/configuration/getting/started/guide/ace_module_gsg/predictr.html)